# Request Token with JQuery from Web API

Tags: jquery, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm doing an ajax-request in Javascript to obtain a JWT from my WebAPI AuthenticationProvider. This is my js-function:

```
    function authenticateUser(credentials) {
    var body = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'myClientId',
        client_secret: 'myClientSecret',
        username: credentials.name,
        password: credentials.password
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/token',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        /* data: JSON.stringify(body), /* wrong */
        data: body, /* right */
        complete: function(result) {
            //called when complete
            alert(result);
        },

        success: function(result) {
            //called when successful
            alert(result);
        },

        error: function(result) {
            //called when there is an error
            alert(result);
        },
    });
    session.isAuthenticated(true);
    return true;
}
```

Although the content is sent the right way in my eyes, the **OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext** has only null values.

My Form Data copied from the console:

> {"grant_type":"password","client_id":"myClientId","client_secret":"myClientSecret","username":"demo","password":"123"}

Comment: your Ajax request looks similar to the ones I have used. Main difference I notice is stringifying the payload data. Do you have to do this? I never have.

Comment: That's the point. Thank you David.

Comment: no problem. Glad it was a simple change because it seemed like this was on the right track :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you may have already solved it but, this is what did it for me.  Using the above and setting body to this worked.

```
var body = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: credentials.name,
    password: credentials.password
};
```