# Get access token for web api using Jquery

Tags: ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am having a WEB API with Token based Authentication. When i make a request in console application using HTTP client its properly executed. The code to execute is

```
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiBaseUrl + "token");
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret)
            };
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I want to make the same request using Ajax. But it shows bad request.

```
    window.jQuery.ajax({
    "url": "http://localhost:63297/token",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "timeout": 10000,
    "data": {
        "client_id": "",
        "client_secret": "",
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    //Write code to be executed when the request SUCCEEDS.
}).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //Write code to be executed when the request FAILS.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the ajax type to post and content type,
 contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
Also refer the below issue for further details, 
[Request Token with JQuery from Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321182/request-token-with-jquery-from-web-api)

Thanks,
Nagaraj M.

Comment: Isn't it set by default in POST type? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server